# What do you see if you enter 'clip' in the Windows 10 Search Box or Cortana?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms, word-in-context

I thought I made a mistake and inputed the word 'clip' in the search box and I saw that I hit the snipping tool which was really what I wanted.

But the question arises:

Are clip and snip in this scenario a synonym? Or it has just learned to adjust to my habit? I thought I may have entered 'clip' before and just found I was wrong and then entered 'snip' and it therefore leaned to correct me silently, which seems horrible to me as an English learner.

What's going on?

Comment: Based on the title, thought this was going to be about a Clippy easter egg.

Comment: "It looks like you're searching for a way to reanimate my digital corpse.  Can I help you with that?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Screen **clipping** and **snipping** are synonymous in this context, and both are used by Microsoft. All copies of Microsoft Windows from version 7 onwards will display this behaviour.

While the built-in screenshot tool in Windows 7 and up is called the *Snipping tool*, a functionally identical tool is found in Microsoft Office programs under the heading *Screen clipping* (Look at `Insert` > `Screenshot` > `Screen clipping`). Microsoft therefore thought it prudent to tag the Snipping tool with the word **clip** and derivatives as well.

Both terms carry similar connotations of cutting part of something away from the larger body.